# Vulkan GLFW include errors in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, glfw

I'm trying to use GLFW in Visual Studio for a Vulkan project.
After all the include statements the code still shows some errors, all of which are related to GLFW library inclusion.
And one error(the last one below) has "stdafx.h" error.
I have no idea what `stdafx.h` is.
I'm posting the Code and the errors.
Can someone help me with this?

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE
#include <glm/vec4.hpp>
#include <glm/mat4x4.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Vulkan window", nullptr, nullptr);
    uint32_t extensionCount = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, nullptr);
    std::cout << extensionCount << " extensions supported" << std::endl;
    glm::mat4 matrix;
    glm::vec4 vec;
    auto test = matrix * vec;
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
>   (active)  E1696   cannot open source file
>   "GLFW/glfw3.h"    VulkanTest  c:\Users\H281525\source\repos\VulkanTest\VulkanTest\main.cpp    2
>
> Error (active)    E0020   identifier "glfwInit" is
>   undefined VulkanTest  c:\Users\H281525\source\repos\VulkanTest\VulkanTest\main.cpp    9
>
> Error (active)    E0020   identifier "glfwWindowHint" is
>   undefined VulkanTest  c:\Users\H281525\source\repos\VulkanTest\VulkanTest\main.cpp    10
>
> Error (active)    E0020   identifier "GLFW_CLIENT_API" is
>   undefined VulkanTest  c:\Users\H281525\source\repos\VulkanTest\VulkanTest\main.cpp    10
>
> Error (active)    E0020   identifier "GLFW_NO_API" is
>   undefined VulkanTest  c:\Users\H281525\source\repos\VulkanTest\VulkanTest\main.cpp    10
>
> Error (active)    E0020   identifier "GLFWwindow" is
>   undefined VulkanTest  c:\Users\H281525\source\repos\VulkanTest\VulkanTest\main.cpp    11
>
> Error (active)    E0020   identifier "window" is
>   undefined VulkanTest  c:\Users\H281525\source\repos\VulkanTest\VulkanTest\main.cpp    11
>
> Error (active)    E0020   identifier "glfwCreateWindow" is
>   undefined VulkanTest  c:\Users\H281525\source\repos\VulkanTest\VulkanTest\main.cpp    11
>
> Error (active)    E0020   identifier
>   "vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties" is
>   undefined VulkanTest  c:\Users\H281525\source\repos\VulkanTest\VulkanTest\main.cpp    13
>
> Error (active)    E0020   identifier "glfwWindowShouldClose" is
>   undefined VulkanTest  c:\Users\H281525\source\repos\VulkanTest\VulkanTest\main.cpp    18
>
> Error (active)    E0020   identifier "glfwPollEvents" is
>   undefined VulkanTest  c:\Users\H281525\source\repos\VulkanTest\VulkanTest\main.cpp    19
>
> Error (active)    E0020   identifier "glfwDestroyWindow" is
>   undefined VulkanTest  c:\Users\H281525\source\repos\VulkanTest\VulkanTest\main.cpp    21
>
> Error (active)    E0020   identifier "glfwTerminate" is
>   undefined VulkanTest  c:\Users\H281525\source\repos\VulkanTest\VulkanTest\main.cpp    22
>
> Error C1010   unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled
>   header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your
>   source?   VulkanTest  c:\users\h281525\source\repos\vulkantest\vulkantest\main.cpp    25

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

> E1696 cannot open source file "GLFW/glfw3.h"

Quite self-explanatory. The compiler cannot find the `GLFW/glfw3.h`. Just add the directory containing the `GLFW` folder into your *Additional Include Directories*.

> E0020 identifier "glfwWhatever" is undefined

Direct result of the above, because the `#include` failed.

> Error C1010 unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header.

If you do not want to use *Precompiled Header*, then just disable it in Project Properties. Otherwise it has to be provided (by default `stdafx.h`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I figured it out and the code is now running :D